# BC30456 VB subroutine is not a member of class file

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors

I have already asked DevExpress this question which they have told me I have problem with my code that involves deleting a row from a DevExpress Gridview.  Basically, I have a VB code-behind routine:

```
Protected Sub ASPxGridViewUnscheduledReviews_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs) Handles ASPxGridViewUnscheduledReviews.RowDeleting
    'Dim aspxGridView As ASPxGridView = sender
    Dim StatusID As Integer = CType(e.Keys("AcrStatusID"), Integer)

    'delete row from ACRStatus table where AcrStatusID = StatusID
    Try
        lblMessage.Text = String.Empty
        'Dim bl As New CYCIS_BL.Reviews
        CYCIS_DL.Reviews.**UnscheduledReviewDelete(StatusID)**

        Response.Redirect("ACR_RemoveUnSchReview.aspx")

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message
    End Try

End Sub
```

where *UnscheduledReviewDelete(StatusID)* calls a Public Shared Sub from a Data Layer Reviews.vb class, which in turn executes an SQL stored procedure to delete the selected record.

The subroutine in Reviews is:

```
Public Shared Sub UnscheduledReviewDelete(ByVal StatusID As Integer)
    Using dbManager As New DBManager(DataProviderEnums.SqlServer, SQLConnectionHelper.CONN_STRING)
        Try
            With dbManager
                .Open()
                .CreateParameters(1)
                .AddParameters(0, "@StatusID", StatusID)
                .ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "UnscheduledReviewDelete")
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

I have saved and built and rebuilt the class file and solution several times.  and yet every time I build the solution the compiler throws this same error and the dynamic metadata of Reviews class shows every routine and function except for the one above.  Why is it not recognizing the subroutine as part of the Reviews class?

Comment: Please provide exact error message.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Column Source Tool
Error  BC30456 'UnscheduledReviewDelete' is not a member of 'Reviews'. CYCIS C:\Workspace\AdministrativeCaseReview(RON) - ACR\ACR Online\ACR_RemoveUnSchReview.aspx.vb 166 4 IntelliSense Compiler

Its not a spelling typo as the names were cut and pasted to be sure that it wasn't.